# IIS Web Hosting Issue on Azure Windows VM

Tags: azure, iis, iis-8

I have a some weird issue with my hosted website on Azure Windows VM box on IIS 8.

I have setup 3 websites on IIS inside Azure Windows VM. The problem with rest of two site is that both of them are pointing to first website source code while the newly 2 websites are having different folder pointing with different folder of source code.

I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: I guess the problem come from your binding host header, they are all pointing to the same site. Try to specify different domains name for them and clean DNS cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue after doing long research. The issue is not with the folder location but with the leaving the host name blank for all and pointing to same port. So all routing was pointing to first website.